# Missing required key :id on new photo form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have **Photo** model which belongs to **User** model. Rails returns this error whenever I try to access new view for `/users/4/photos/new`:

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photos", :user_id=>"4"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

This is my *PhotosController*:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
    def index
        find_user
        @photos = @user.photos
    end

    def new
        find_user
        @photo = @user.photos.build
    end

    def show
        find_photo
    end

    def create
        @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])

        if @photo.save

            if params[:images]
                params[:images].each { |image|
                    @user.photos.create(image: image)
                }
            end

        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        find_user
        @photo = @user.photos.find(params[:id])

        if @photo.update
            redirect_to photos_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        find_photo
        @photo.destroy

        redirect_to photos_path
    end

    private

    def find_user
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    def find_photo
        @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def photo_params
        require(:photo).permit(:title, :image, :user_id)
    end
end
```

And this is my *_form* partial for photos views.

```
<%= form_for @photo, :html => { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true } do |f| %>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class: "input-field form-control" %>

<%= f.label :pictures %>
<%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiplue: true %>

<%= f.submit nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

I don't understand how ID is missing, I'm providing it via *find_user* method.

Update:

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#index'

  # prevedene rute
  get "/pocetna"          => "welcome#index", as: "index" 
  get "/o-sajtu"          => "welcome#about", as: "about"
  get "/moj-profil"       => "users#show", as: "profile"
  post "/users"         => "users#create"
  get "/users"          => "users#index", as: "users"
  get "/user"           => "users#index"
  get "/users/:id"       => "users#show", as: "user"
  get "/users/:id/edit" => "users#edit", as: "edit_user"
  patch "/users/:id"     => "users#update"
  get "/users/add"    => "users#new", as: "new_user"

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  get "/login"   => "sessions#new", as: "login"
  post "/login"  => "sessions#create"
  get "/logout"    => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
  delete "/logout" => "sessions#destroy"

  resources :users do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

**Update**
I get new error now

```
undefined method `photos_path' for #<<Class:0x007f4f14f16160>:0x00000004f040e8>
```

First line of the form is marked.

Comment: where is your `routes.rb` code?

Comment: @Emu I've updated the question.

Comment: also add the link which you are using to create new photo

Comment: @pavan How do you mean link i'm using to create new photo? I'm using `/users/:id/photos/new`

Comment: yes the path helper which you add to link_to may be like this link_to "new photo", new_user_photo_path(@user)

Comment: @pavan It still shows me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your form_for in  _form partial to

```
form_for([@user, @photo]) do |f|
#rest of your code
end
```

Comment: Thanks! How dumb of me, I haven't even noticed that.

Comment: and also the way your are calling methods find_user and find_photo in controller  is not correct use before_action filters

Comment: when I add it in before action `before_action :find_user, :find_photo` , I get this error: `Couldn't find Photo with 'id'=`

Comment: before_action :find_user, only: [:index, :new, :create, :update]
before_action :find_photo, only: [:show, :destroy]

Answer (score 0):

How do you call the /users/4/photos/new in your view? Ideally you should pass the user_id as id not as user_id. Once, you do that this issue should be resolved.

Comment: I need to pass user_id in Photos controller because id is reserver for photo id. user_id is reference to the user. In new view I'm rendering that form.